# Javascript - How to get multiple data attribute of button when on click

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I have multiple buttons with a `data-rel` attribute, how do I get that attribute on each button when they are clicked?

HTML

```
<button class="category" data-rel="all">All</button>
<button class="category" data-rel="banana">Banana</button>
<button class="category" data-rel="orange">Orange</button>
<button class="category" data-rel="watermelon">Watermelon</button>
```

JS

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.category');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var el = btn.getAttribute('data-rel');      
  alert(el);
})
```

I'm only able to get the attribute for the first button, but not the rest

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.category');
    
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var el = btn.getAttribute('data-rel');      
  alert(el);
})
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="category" data-rel="all">All</button>
<button class="category" data-rel="banana">Banana</button>
<button class="category" data-rel="orange">Orange</button>
<button class="category" data-rel="watermelon">Watermelon</button>
```

Comment: With `var btn = document.querySelector('.category');` you only get the first matching element. Use `querySelectorAll` instead.

Comment: do you want to get the attribute only from the button clicked or all of them irregardless of which one is clicked on?

Comment: @ochi only from the button that i clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you want a single function to handle every button. Therefore I declare the function outside of the loop, so it is declared only one time, and therefore saves memory. You are going to need this handle-function regardless of what version you use below to add the event listener.

```
// The handle function is declared outside the loop, saving memory.
// The current button is found in this
// Also using dataset to get the data.
function handle(event) {
  alert( this.dataset.rel );
}
```

To get all matching elements you need to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). It returns a collection, and you can use the *forEach*-method to easily traverse the collection:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.category').forEach(
  function (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', handle );
  }
);
```

This is the same type of call, but with modern arrow-function instead. I don't know what you prefer.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.category').forEach(
  btn => btn.addEventListener('click', handle )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, i was able to get the data attribute value from your first example, however for the second one 'modern javascript', it's like not working ? do i need to do something else ?

Comment: @FarisahChan You still need the *handle*-function. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks @some for your detailed explanation ;-)

Comment: No problem @FarisahChan. Welcome to Stackoverflow and congratulations to your first question!

Comment: @FarisahChan Welcome to SO, congrats on the first question and answer